# Why projective plane $\Bbb RP^2$ contains no two cycles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, simplicial-complex

I am new to simplicial complexes and I am reading a paper on "directed rooted forest in higher dimension" in which in an example it was mentioned that **projective plane of dimension 2 contain no two cycle** but to my understanding when I looked at the triangulation of it I could form a hollow tetrahedron that is a 2 dimension hole. Can someone explain what mistake I am making?

Comment: It would be better if you can include a picture of the triangulation that you mentioned.

Comment: Your cycle should by definition comes with an orientation. If you try to make the orientations compatible between the triangles, you will not succeed (basically because $\mathbb RP^2$ contains a Möbius band).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet thank you I will look into again, I was not considering the orientations. thanks.

Comment: Sure. Actually, if you consider homology with coefficient in a ring of characteristic two, this issue disappear and any triangulation of $\mathbb RP^2$ will give such a $2$-cycles.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I figured it out with your help Thanks.